# Install Sitecore 10.1 via SIF Skip

Tags: installation, sitecore-install-framework

I'm trying to install a fresh installation of Sitecore Experience Platform 10.1 Update-1, as part of my setup I wish to Skip a task or maybe more.

According to the documentation at https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Installation_Framework/2x/Sitecore_Installation_Framework_230.aspx

I should be able to Skip tasks, however it doesn't seem to work. When I open up my XPO-SingleDeveloper.ps1 and add a Skip task to line 80.

```
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @singleDeveloperParams *>&1 | Tee-Object XP0-SingleDeveloper.log -Skip CreateHostHeader
```

I get the following error

```
Tee-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Skip'.
```

[image]
It sounds like the Skip command isn't recognized as the Task does exist in the sitecore-XP0.json file.

I have tried removing the *>&1 | Tee-Object XP0-SingleDeveloper.log but it still doesn't accept the Skip command.

Comment: It is getting passed into the `Tee-Object` now, how did you exactly pass it in when you removed this? It needs to get passed into `Install-SitecoreConfiguration`

Comment: I originally called  Install-SitecoreConfiguration @singleDeveloperParams *>&1 | Tee-Object XP0-SingleDeveloper.log -Skip CreateHostHeader, after that didn't work I removed  *>&1 | Tee-Object XP0-SingleDeveloper.log, I get the following error back Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Could not find Task 'CreateHostHeader' in Skip list

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following example,

```
PS C:\> Install-SitecoreConfiguration -Path .\MyConfig.json -Skip Alpha,Beta
```

What does the above do?

"Starts an installation based on a JSON configuration file and executes all the tasks except the named tasks."

**Reference**
https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/101/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_101_Update1.aspx

You can get more helpful information from the **SIF 2.3.0 Configuration Guide** (which applies for Sitecore XP 10.0.0 - 10.1.1) available for download at the above reference link.

**Complete Installation Syntax:**

```
Install-SitecoreConfiguration [-Path] <String> [[-Tasks] <String[]>] [[-From] <String>] [[-To]
<String>]
[[-Skip] <String[]>] [[-WorkingDirectory] <String>] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>]
```

*CreateHostHeader* is a task found in sitecore-XP0.json

So, I tried modifying the installation syntax in Line #80 like below - still getting an error as the Path parameter was already specified within the @singleDeveloperParams - tried specifying these two params for Parameter still there is some validation issue,

```
Install-SitecoreConfiguration -Path .\sitecore-XP0.json -Skip CreateHostHeader @singleDeveloperParams *>&1 | Tee-Object XP0-SingleDeveloper.log
```

I'll try to fix this and share the updates here.